# Is there any tutorials for visual SLAM (beginners)?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, kinect, monocular-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ros as well as to robotics. I wish to learn some basic tutorials in Visual-SLAM. I tried RGBDSLAM from ros and it works. As I am not good in programming, I can't understand the codes.

So, I would like to learn how to do programming for visual SLAM (c++ or Matlab). Is there any available tutorials for visual SLAM (any webpages or books)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41840/is-there-any-tutorials-for-visual-slam-(beginners)?/) by [chris_chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2965/chris_chris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heromoga2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/20248/heromoga2000/) on 2014-09-20**:
Hello
can you help me to how to make RGBDSLAM work
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Welcome, Chris! If you'd like to work with programming of any sort, I suggest some training in your programming language of choice in the first place. I know it can be a pain for many, but it'll be hard to work past using other people's code on your application if you can't program yourself.

SLAM is not exactly an easy problem to tackle even without considering the programming aspect of it, either. With Visual SLAM, there is an extra amount of work involved in using computer vision for sensor processing (for instance, for matching subsequent image frames). More programming comes in when you have to work with the CV libraries to do that, such as OpenCV.

Here are some references I found useful in the past, although they are not specific to Visual SLAM:

[OpenSLAM](http://openslam.org/) (I recommend Tim Bailey's MATLAB package for beginners)

[SLAM for Dummies](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-412j-cognitive-robotics-spring-2005/projects/1aslam_blas_repo.pdf) (Tutorial)

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tung Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1671/tung-nguyen/) on 2016-01-21**:
It's good to see you everywhere, George!